# How to solve JS array of objects minify problem?

Tags: javascript, minify, uglifyjs

I have a js file which contain one array of objects.

**testsripts.js**

```
[
   {action: t.message, text: ' ==== Test form insertions === \nInserting forms.... \n'}
]
```

when I minified this file using uglifier I am getting similar result as follows.

**testsripts.min.js**

```
t.message;
```

How to solve this.

*(the above scripts are a shortened for simpilicity)*

Comment: Put it in a variable

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign the value for the object seperately.

Replace

```
[
   {action: t.message, text: ' ==== Test form insertions === \nInserting forms.... \n'}
]
```

With

```
var myarray=[];
var obj={};
obj.action=t.message;
obj.text=" ==== Test form insertions === \nInserting forms.... \n";
myarray.push(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have there is an array whose reference isn't saved anywhere. So, rather than creating an array that would be immediately garbage collected, UglifyJS evaluates your code for possible side-effects, and minifies your code so that the expressions that have side-effects run (and the rest are discarded).

The `text` property has just a plain string literal as a value, which can't possibly have any side effects, so it's discarded. The value of `action` is `t.message`, which *could* cause side effects if `message` is a getter. So, the minified result is just `t.message;` and nothing else.

One option is to declare a variable, to ensure the array reference is saved:

```
const arr = [
  {action: t.message, text: ' ==== Test form insertions === \nInserting forms.... \n'}
];
```

Output, you can test [here](https://skalman.github.io/UglifyJS-online/):

```
const arr=[{action:t.message,text:" ==== Test form insertions === \nInserting forms.... \n"}];
```

Comment: I am using js `eval` method on this file content so that file should return an array `t.execute(eval(testsriptsDataString))` is

Comment: Having to resort to `eval` is a sign that you should re-consider your application's design - it's quite inelegant. Consider using something like Webpack so that you can `import` objects, modules properly. If that's not an option, you can `slice` the string before `eval`ing it - eg `t.execute(eval(testsriptsDataString.slice(10)))` so that the initial `const arr=` is dropped.